# How to remove nodejs from Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, uninstall

Steps to replicate:

Ubuntu 16.04 xenial (x86-64)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

I want to uninstall `nodejs` and `npm` and have seen several posts which suggest this is the most common way:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
```

However, this produces a prompt which seems to reference dependencies which, if they were removed, sound like they would cause problems.

What is the best way to "undo" the install of `nodejs` and `npm`?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gyp* libboost-python1.58.0* libjs-inherits* libjs-node-uuid*
  libjs-underscore* libssl-dev* libssl-doc* libuv1* libuv1-dev*
  linux-headers-4.4.0-18* linux-headers-4.4.0-18-generic*
  linux-headers-4.4.0-21* linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic*
  linux-image-4.4.0-18-generic* linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic*
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-18-generic* linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic*
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-18-generic* linux-signed-image-4.4.0-21-generic*
  node-abbrev* node-ansi* node-ansi-color-table* node-archy* node-async*
  node-block-stream* node-combined-stream* node-cookie-jar*
  node-delayed-stream* node-forever-agent* node-form-data* node-fstream*
  node-fstream-ignore* node-github-url-from-git* node-glob* node-graceful-fs*
  node-gyp* node-inherits* node-ini* node-json-stringify-safe* node-lockfile*
  node-lru-cache* node-mime* node-minimatch* node-mkdirp* node-mute-stream*
  node-node-uuid* node-nopt* node-normalize-package-data* node-npmlog*
  node-once* node-osenv* node-qs* node-read* node-read-package-json*
  node-request* node-retry* node-rimraf* node-semver* node-sha* node-sigmund*
  node-slide* node-tar* node-tunnel-agent* node-underscore* node-which*
  nodejs* nodejs-dev* npm* python-configobj* python-pycurl* python-pyexiv2*
  python-pyexiv2-doc*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 72 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 631 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

**Edit:**

This is the output from `sudo apt-get purge nodejs`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libboost-python1.58.0 libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore
  libssl-dev libssl-doc libuv1 libuv1-dev linux-headers-4.4.0-18
  linux-headers-4.4.0-18-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-21
  linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-4.4.0-18-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-18-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-18-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-21-generic python-configobj python-pycurl
  python-pyexiv2 python-pyexiv2-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  node-abbrev* node-ansi* node-ansi-color-table* node-archy* node-async*
  node-block-stream* node-combined-stream* node-cookie-jar*
  node-delayed-stream* node-forever-agent* node-form-data* node-fstream*
  node-fstream-ignore* node-github-url-from-git* node-glob* node-graceful-fs*
  node-gyp* node-inherits* node-ini* node-json-stringify-safe* node-lockfile*
  node-lru-cache* node-mime* node-minimatch* node-mkdirp* node-mute-stream*
  node-node-uuid* node-nopt* node-normalize-package-data* node-npmlog*
  node-once* node-osenv* node-qs* node-read* node-read-package-json*
  node-request* node-retry* node-rimraf* node-semver* node-sha* node-sigmund*
  node-slide* node-tar* node-tunnel-agent* node-underscore* node-which*
  nodejs* nodejs-dev* npm*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 49 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 27.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Possibly many extraneous packages from `autoremove`. What happens when you just run `sudo apt-get purge nodejs`?

Comment: How about trying http://stackoverflow.com/a/33947181/486919?

Comment: @heemayl - have added output to post, and just went ahead with that approach.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

As seen from the output of:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

it is only removing `node` related packages i.e. relevant packages, nothing more.

On the other hand, when you do:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
```

it is essentially doing:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and the removal of the `gyp`, `linux-headers-4.4.0-18-generic` etc packages are actually triggered by `autoremove` as they were installed as dependencies and no longer needed by any installed package, presumably because the main package has been removed.

So it is perfectly fine in this context to run:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
```

If you are too paranoid, you can do it in two steps: first `purge nodejs`:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

and then remove the orphan dependencies (till now, if any):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 26):

To remove node js, npm and  node_modules from Ubuntu,  you need to remove containers also which are at different locations in Ubuntu.
These could be as:

`/usr/local/bin/npm`, `/usr/local/share/man/man1/node`, `/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d`, `~/.npm ~/.node-gyp`, `/opt/local/bin/node`, `opt/local/include/node`, `/opt/local/lib/node_modules`

I have posted the procedure to remove NodeJS on my blog: [AMCOS IT Support For Windows and Linux: To completely uninstall node js from Ubuntu](https://web.archive.org/web/20161114130923/http://amcositsupport.blogspot.in/2016/07/to-completely-uninstall-node-js-from.html).

> 1. First of all you need to run the following command from command terminal as sudo.
>
>    ```
>    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
>    ```
> 2. Remove node or node_modules directories from /usr/local/lib with the help of following command.
>
>    ```
>    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
>    ```
> 3. Remove node or node_modules directories from /usr/local/include with the help of following command.
>
>    ```
>    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
>    ```
> 4. Remove any node file or dir from /usr/local/bin with the help of following command.
>
>    ```
>    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
>    ```
> 5. Go to home directory and remove any node or node_modules directory, if exists.

Comment: This was helpful - even after the `purge` commands, even after restarting, these binaries where still left over and acting like node/npm was still installed and all. Only after removing the binaries is a full uninstall complete.

Answer (score 12):

`sudo apt-get remove nodejs`

`sudo apt-get remove npm`

Then go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and remove any node list if you have. Then do a

`sudo apt-get update`

Check for any .npm or .node folder in your home folder and delete those.

If you type

`which node`

you can see the location of the node. Try `which nodejs` and `which npm` too.

I would recommend installing node using Node Version Manager(NVM). That saved a lot of head ache for me. Because you can install nodejs and npm without sudo using nvm.

Comment: which command should I use to remove nodes in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` ? what should I remove? I have `nodesource.list`!  so probably `sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesources.list*` ?

Comment: Yes, run `sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesources.list*` to remove nodejs source from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

Answer (score 6):

To manually remove `nodejs`, `npm` and  `node_modules` from Ubuntu, you need to do the following steps:

1. Run the following command from the terminal as `sudo`:

   ```
    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node /opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
   ```
2. Remove `node` or `node_modules` directories from `/usr/local/lib` with the help of the following command:

   ```
    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
   ```
3. Remove `node` or `node_modules` directories from `/usr/local/include` with the help of the following command:

   ```
    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
   ```
4. Remove any `node` file or directory from `/usr/local/bin` with the help of the following command:

   ```
    sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
   ```
5. Go to your home directory and remove any `node` or `node_modules` directory, if exists.

Now it is done.

Comment: This worked.  The accepted answer (`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs`) still left `/usr/local/bin/node` on my ubuntu 18.04 machine.

Answer (score 5):

I had this challenge when working on an **Ubuntu 20.04** machine with **Nodejs**.

For me, I had to run the following commands to remove nodejs and all of it's dependencies.

This is to remove nodejs and it's dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

This is to remove any dependencies that are still left after removing nodejs

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This is to remove the nodejs repository from the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list*
```

Update your package repository list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Confirm if the node executable is still available in your machine:

```
which node
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**