# After installation NodeJS, my system can't run node command

Tags: apt, system-installation, nodejs, mint

help me please install `NodeJs` on my Ubuntu. I do

## Using Ubuntu

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and after installation, I do:

```
node -v
```

and get message like

```
"Programm node isn't installed yet, you can install it by doing `sudo apt install nodejs-legacy`"
```

I already installed and removed `nodejs-legacy`, but still, when I try to run `nodejs -v`, I get 4.2.6

And sorry for not perfect English, please help me.

Comment: The installation probably didn't finish due to an error. Have a look at the output in the terminal and see if you can find some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation for Ubuntu and derivatives is very simple. Before installing be sure to uninstall the old nodeJS

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Check if in some of the commands you do not get an error.

To remove the nodeJS please see the following post : [How to remove nodejs from Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thank you, I used recommendations from post which you pointed.
I read logs of curl command and find next thing.

Not found 
- http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexx2000/xUbuntu_18.3/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]

probably it's important for succesfully install nodejs