# how can I delete node js nightly?

Tags: 20.04, nodejs, software-uninstall, npm

I've tried various ways to clear this version of NodeJs.
But in the end, this version is not deleted!

I tried several methods like this:
[How to remove nodejs from Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04)

[image]

Comment: How did you install nodejs? Looks like you haven't used apt.So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917184/11970791) might help you.

Comment: my problem solved just uninstall from ubuntu software center