# npm does not support Node.js v10.19.0

Tags: apt, nodejs, npm

npm does not support Node.js v10.19.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

Comment: I had the same problem
I installed node from the snap-store[Using Snap Store To Install Nodejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzWfK.png)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Short Answer

The simplest is to update to Node.js v14:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

If you having problems installing try `sudo apt-get purge nodejs`, see [details](https://askubuntu.com/a/786019/676490).

### Long Answer

You could update to newer Node.js-versions, see:
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#readme
however according to [a comment on github](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3644#issuecomment-996048756), jumping to the newest version, might lead to breaking changes. (I don't notice any.)

Thanks to a comment from [@SaidbakR](https://askubuntu.com/users/217641/saidbakr) below : To see which version is compatible check the [following table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass):

---

```
| NodeJS  | `npm --version` |
|---------|-----------------|
| Node 20 | 9.0+            |
| Node 18 | 8.0+            |
| Node 16 | 6.0+            |
| Node 14 | 4.14+, <9.0     |
| Node 12 | 4.12+, <8.0     |
| Node 10 | 4.9+ , <6.0     |
```

---

I skipped the uneven numbers, because they don't have a long-term-support.

If you would like to update to e.g. Node.js 18, edit the number from the code above:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
if [ -f "/etc/debian_version" ]; then
 sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
fi
```

This answer is based on ([How to update node.js](https://askubuntu.com/a/548776/676490)) as well on  ([compatible node.js and npm-Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69120428/6747994))

Comment: For those having an ERROR `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bluetooth/bluez/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`, just run `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:bluetooth/bluez` and you will be able to run the above commands

Comment: I'd like to combine this answer with [**That Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69120428/1592845) on the Stack Overflow. Both of them offers complete solution npm running issues

Answer (score 1):

If you have `nvm` you can try re-installing node versions. Make sure you switch to the version of node for which your npm works first. For example switch to node 8 and then re-install other versions.

```
nvm use 8
nvm uninstall 10
nvm uninstall  12
nvm install 10
nvm install 12
nvm use 10
nvm alias default 10   
nvm uninstall 8
```

Source: [maxbettercloud](https://github.com/maxbettercloud) on https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3644#issuecomment-999170850

Comment: And to list all available versions do `nvm ls-remote`.

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2023:

node.js changed the installation: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
NODE_MAJOR=18
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
```

PS: You can change the Version by choosing one of the following:
`NODE_MAJOR=16`;`NODE_MAJOR=18`;`NODE_MAJOR=20`